# Use google cloud mysql database in .net application on local machine

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

How can we use google cloud database for local.net web application without deployed .net app on google cloud?

Comment: What database do you want you use?

Comment: using MySQL database

Comment: Can you give some details about what problems you are running into.  For example, have you followed the instructions on [this page](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app) for connecting to a Cloud SQL instance from an external application?

Answer (score 0):

You can connect directly to Cloud SQL using either of the following options:

- [whitelisting your IP address](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ip#add) and connect using the Public IP of your instance
- you can [run the Cloud SQL proxy locally](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/quickstart-proxy-test) which will forward the traffic to the instance